# I'm struggling to write this function to wrap (case-insensitive) matches of a substring in <b></b>, but keep the case of the matched content

Tags: javascript

I found doing case insensitive matching, but replacing the matches with the case of the original content - not the searched content - was not exactly trivial. Or at least more complicated than the similar version of this where you replace matches for a substring. How can I do this? I'm too many hours into what should be a simple part of my app. The code's test cases should clarify the question.

```js
// Want to wrap instances of a substring (matching case-INsensitive)
// with <b> and </b>, but maintain the case-sensitivity of the source.

function regEscape(v) {
    return v.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&')
}

function boldSubstring(source, substr) {
    const regx = new RegExp(regEscape(substr), "ig")
    const indices = [...source.matchAll(regx)].map(a => a.index)
    
    // filter: I actually don't know why these empty matches are 
    // happening; this is a patch. Might be wrong.
    const parts = source.split(regx).filter(part => part !== '')
    
    // Here we add our inserted parts.
    const updatedParts = parts.slice(0)
    let result
    for (let i = 0, j = 0; i < parts.length; i += 1, j += 2) {
        let joiner = '<b>' + source.slice(indices[i], indices[i] + substr.length) + '</b>'
        updatedParts.splice(j, 0, joiner)
    }
    return updatedParts.join('')
}

const searchStr1 = 't'

const tests1 = [
  {
    in: 'Default description.',
    out: 'Defaul<b>t</b> descrip<b>t</b>ion.'
  },
  {
    in: 'Tiger toe',
    out: '<b>T</b>iger <b>t</b>oe'
  },
  {
    in: 'TTiger ttoe',
    out: '<b>T</b><b>T</b>iger <b>t</b><b>t</b>oe'
  },
  {
    in: 'T1234',
    out: '<b>T</b>1234'
  },
  {
    in: 't1234',
    out: '<b>t</b>1234'
  },
]

const searchStr2 = 'ti'

const tests2 = [
  {
    in: 'Default description.',
    out: 'Default description.'
  },
  {
    in: 'Tiger toe',
    out: '<b>Ti</b>ger toe'
  },
  {
    in: 'TTiger ttoe',
    out: 'T<b>Ti</b>ger ttoe'
  },
  {
    in: 'T1234',
    out: 'T1234'
  },
  {
    in: 't1234',
    out: 't1234'
  },
]

function test(search, tests) {
  tests.forEach(testPair => {
    const result = boldSubstring(testPair.in, search)
    const passed = result === testPair.out
    if (passed) console.log('Passing:', result, '===', testPair.out)
    else console.log('Failing:', result, '!==', testPair.out)
  })
}

test(searchStr1, tests1)
test(searchStr2, tests2)
```

I bet I'm wildly over-thinking this.

Comment: In the second one, why is `Default description.` not `Default descrip<b>ti</b>on.`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `Default description` should  be `Default descrip<b>ti</b>on.` in your second test case, you can make this simpler by using [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```js
source.replace(regx, "<b>$&</b>");
```

By using a replacement argument of `"<b>$&</b>"`, you're telling replace to replace all matches of your regular expression with that match ([`$&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_string_as_the_replacement)) wrapped in `<b></b>` tags.

```js
// Want to wrap instances of a substring (matching case-INsensitive)
// with <b> and </b>, but maintain the case-sensitivity of the source.

function regEscape(v) {
    return v.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&')
}

function boldSubstring(source, substr) {
    const regx = new RegExp(regEscape(substr), "ig")
    return source.replace(regx, "<b>$&</b>");
}

const searchStr1 = 't';
const tests1 = [ { in: 'Default description.', out: 'Defaul<b>t</b> descrip<b>t</b>ion.' }, { in: 'Tiger toe', out: '<b>T</b>iger <b>t</b>oe' }, { in: 'TTiger ttoe', out: '<b>T</b><b>T</b>iger <b>t</b><b>t</b>oe' }, { in: 'T1234', out: '<b>T</b>1234' }, { in: 't1234', out: '<b>t</b>1234' }, ];

const searchStr2 = 'ti'
const tests2 = [ { in: 'Default description.', out: 'Default descrip<b>ti</b>on.' }, { in: 'Tiger toe', out: '<b>Ti</b>ger toe' }, { in: 'TTiger ttoe', out: 'T<b>Ti</b>ger ttoe' }, { in: 'T1234', out: 'T1234' }, { in: 't1234', out: 't1234' }, ];


function test(search, tests) {
  tests.forEach(testPair => {
    const result = boldSubstring(testPair.in, search)
    const passed = result === testPair.out
    if (passed) console.log('Passing:', result, '===', testPair.out)
    else console.log('Failing:', result, '!==', testPair.out)
  })
}

test(searchStr1, tests1);
test(searchStr2, tests2);
```

Comment: Yes I did mess up that test case. It was this easy?? Wow.